# Girar Rectángulo con LibGDX

Tags: android, libgdx

Estoy haciendo un programilla de prueba que se compone de :

- 4 botones , arriba, abajo, izquierda y derecha.
- Una nave espacial, formada por un Rectangulo(`Rectangle`) y su respectiva imagen (`Texture`).

`Boton arriba,` se mueve hacia arriba

`Boton abajo`, se mueve hacia abajo.

`Boton izquierdo`, gira en sentido antihorario sobre si mismo
`Boton derecho` , gira en sentido horario sobre si mismo

No encuentro ningun método para hacer funcionar el boton derecho e izquierdo. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar también la clase `Polygon` en lugar de `Rectangle`

a diferencia del rectangulo el polygono se define segun sus vertices:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Polygon polygono = new Polygon(new float[]{
                rect.x, rect.y,                                 //vertice A
                rect.x, rect.y + rect.height,                   //vertice B
                rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height,     //vertice C
                rect.x + rect.width, rect.y                    //vertice D
            });


botonIzquierdo.addListener(new InputListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                    int pointer, int button) {

        polygono.rotate(5);
        return super.touchDown(event, x, y, pointer, button);
    }
});
```

En render();

```
shapeRenderer.begin();
shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.red);
shapeRenderer.polygon(polygono.getTransformedVertices());
shapeRenderer.end();
```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno he conseguido ver como solucionar este error sencillito.

Si creamos el `Rectangle` no vamos a poder manipularlo mucho, deberiamos crear un `ShapeRender` :
Creamos cuatro puntos

```
float shapeX = new float[4];
float shapeY = new float[4];
```

y ahora en nuestro `void draw()`

```
shapeX[0] = x + MathUtils.cos(radians);
shapeY[0] = x + MathUtils.sin(radians);
```

Le damos valor a radians, al punto principal le doy pi/2 , y ya le vamos sumando su respectivo angulo a cada punto. Hacemos esto con cada punto del array.